# Why does loading all stores for a website depend on what store is currently loaded?

Tags: php, magento

In Magento, there are several ways of how all stores for one or more website can be loaded. You could either do a `Mage::app()->getStores(true)` or a `Mage::app()->getWebsites()` and then walk through all stores in the resulting collection. This [has already been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867647/gettiing-a-list-of-magento-stores). What I discovered recently is, that *loading a store before calling one of the methods above, is affecting the result*. Especially regarding the default store. Example:

**Setup**: 1 Website with 3 Stores (`english`, `french`, `german`, while `german` is the default store)

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->load(0); // load admin store (or any other)
foreach (Mage::app()->getStores(true) as $store) {
    echo "\n" . $store->getId() . " - " . $store->getCode();
} 
result is: 
0 - admin
1 - english
3 - french

Mage::app()->getStore()->load(2); // load german store (default)
foreach (Mage::app()->getStores(true) as $store) {
    echo "\n" . $store->getId() . " - " . $store->getCode();
} 
result is: 
0 - admin
1 - english
3 - french
2 - german
```

Even stranger things happen when I'm browsing through the website to get it's stores. The default store's values are replaced with the values of the currenly loaded store:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->load(0); // load admin store
foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
    foreach ($website->getStores() as $store) {
        echo "\n".$store->getId() . ' - ' . $store->getCode();
    }
}
result: 
1 - english
3 - french
0 - admin

in case of Mage::app()->getStore()->load(1) the result is:
1 - english
3 - french
1 - english
```

The only proper way I could get all stores a website independent of the currently loaded store was like this:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->load($anyStoreId); // load any store
/** @var $websites Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website_Collection */
$websites = Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_collection');
foreach ($websites as $website) {
    foreach ($website->getStores() as $store) {
        echo "\n".$store->getId() . ' - ' . $store->getCode();
    }
}
result is always:
1 - english
3 - french
2 - german
```

What is the reason for these results? Is this a bug in Magento or is this behaviour intended? And are there better ways of how to load a website's stores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the method `Mage_Core_Model_App::getStore()`.
It accepts a parameter called `$id` but if that is null the current store is returned:

```
if (!isset($id) || ''===$id || $id === true) {
     $id = $this->_currentStore;
}
```

Now...calling `->load()` on a model, modifies the current object.
So when you call `Mage::app()->getStore()->load(0)` it has the following effect:

1. You retrieve the current store
2. You load the store with id 0 (admin)
3. Since objects are passed by reference you end up having in `Mage_Core_Model_App::_currentStore` the admin store.

And since `Mage_Core_Model_App` is instantiated as a singleton in the rest of the script you will have the admin store as the current store.

Further more, at the end of the same method there are these lines:

```
$this->_stores[$store->getStoreId()] = $store;
$this->_stores[$store->getCode()] = $store;
```

This caches the results of `getStore` in a member variable so you won't have to load it an other time. And `_stores` is used when calling `getStores()`.
**Conclusion.**: Calling `Mage::getStore()->load()` can do much harm to your script. Calling this on a frontend page may result in access to some admin methods (not controllers or actions though). To iterate through stores and website you the `Mage::getResourceModel()` approach.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But anyway, I find it a bit strange that the result of `Mage::app()->getStores()` can depend on what store is loaded. I do not always have control over this, for example someone could call `Mage::app()->getStore()->load(1)` in an observer before I try to get the stores.

Comment: @JanWy You don't need to use `Mage::app()->getStore()->load(1)`. Just use `$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(1)`